# Simplify select using hierarchy function

Tags: abap, hierarchy

I wonder if it could be possible to simplify the following ABAP-based `TDEVC` selection using the new hierarchy functions of ABAP SQL.

Table `TDEVC` is SAP's table of packages (= development classes), with the columns `(DEVCLASS,PARENTCL)` definig the hierarchy.

The goal is to list each package in the custom namespace, whose name starts with the letter `Z`, together with its parent package and its root package (the uniquely defined ancestor with `PARENTCL = ''`.

This would be the selection *without* hierarchy, performed with plain old ABAP. I didn't succeed to define `TDEVC` as a hierarchy source in the `SELECT` statement itself, as described in the [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenselect_hierarchy_definition.htm).

```
types:
  begin of ty_node,
    devclass type devclass,
    parentcl type devclass,
    root     type devclass,
  end of ty_node,
  ty_nodes type sorted table of ty_node
    with non-unique key parentcl.

data:
  lt_nodes type ty_nodes,
  lt_root type ty_nodes,
  lt_parents type ty_nodes.

field-symbols:
  <ls_node> type ty_node,
  <ls_parent> type ty_node.

select devclass, parentcl from tdevc
  into table @lt_nodes
  where devclass like 'Z%'.

loop at lt_nodes assigning <ls_node>
  where parentcl eq ''.
  insert value #(
    devclass = <ls_node>-devclass
    root     = <ls_node>-devclass )
    into table lt_root.
  delete lt_nodes.
endloop.

lt_parents = lt_root.
while lt_parents is not initial.
  data(lt_parents_new) = value ty_nodes(  ).
  loop at lt_parents assigning <ls_parent>.
    loop at lt_nodes assigning <ls_node>
      where parentcl = <ls_parent>-devclass.
      <ls_node>-root = <ls_parent>-root.
      insert <ls_node> into table lt_parents_new.
    endloop.
  endloop.
  lt_parents = lt_parents_new.
endwhile.
* Result is now in lt_nodes
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to a make a selection using hierarchy functionality in the following way:

```
WITH
  +tdevc_source AS
  ( SELECT FROM tdevc
      FIELDS devclass AS id, parentcl AS parent, parentcl AS root
      WHERE devclass LIKE 'Z%' )
    WITH ASSOCIATIONS
  ( JOIN TO MANY +tdevc_source AS _tdevc ON +tdevc_source~parent = _tdevc~id ),


  +tdevc_hierarchy AS
  ( SELECT FROM HIERARCHY( SOURCE +tdevc_source
                           CHILD TO PARENT ASSOCIATION _tdevc
                           START WHERE parent IS INITIAL
                           SIBLINGS ORDER BY id
                           MULTIPLE PARENTS NOT ALLOWED
                          ) AS cte_hierarchy
    FIELDS id, parent, root )
    WITH HIERARCHY cte_hierarchy


   SELECT FROM +tdevc_hierarchy
     FIELDS
       id, parent, root,
       hierarchy_rank, hierarchy_parent_rank
     INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_nodes).
```

We use **common table expressions** (CTEs) to define the internal ABAP SQL definition of data sources.

Additionally two extra fields `hierarchy_rank` and `hierarchy_parent_rank` are selected, which reflect the hierarchical relations between records.

The requirement says, that the result should contain different hierarchy level objects in every single row (up to a root package), so the final processing of the internal result table is necessary to achieve this, for example:

```
LOOP AT lt_nodes ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_node>).
  DATA(lv_hpr) = <fs_node>-hierarchy_parent_rank.
  WHILE lv_hpr > 0.
    ASSIGN lt_nodes[ hierarchy_rank = lv_hpr ] TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_node_root>).
    lv_hpr = <fs_node_root>-hierarchy_parent_rank.
    IF lv_hpr = 0.
      <fs_node>-root = <fs_node_root>-id.
    ENDIF.
  ENDWHILE.
ENDLOOP.
DELETE lt_nodes WHERE hierarchy_parent_rank = 0.
```